# CSS Flex Container background not covering all the content and is not rectangular

Tags: css

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mbd7F.png)

I need to place a rectangular background below the submenus instead of a background under each element separately.
Vertical Menu code:

```
nav.top_menu > ul > li.vertical-menu .sub-menu {box-shadow: none;}
nav.top_menu > ul > li.vertical-menu > .sub-menu{padding: 10px 0;}
nav.top_menu > ul > li.vertical-menu > .sub-menu{border: 2px solid transparent; border-top: none; width:auto; min-width:150px;}
.vertical-menu .border-grey-bottom{margin-bottom: 10px}
nav.top_menu > ul > li.vertical-menu ul li.menu-item > a{padding: 9px 16px; font-size: 14px; border:none; background: white;}
nav.top_menu > ul > li.vertical-menu > ul > li > ul > li > ul > li > a{padding: 7px 12px; font-size: 13px;}
nav.top_menu > ul > li.vertical-menu > ul > li > .sub-menu {     position: fixed;     min-height: calc(100% + 2px);     display: flex;     height: auto;     flex-flow: column wrap;     max-height: 70vh;     background: white;     padding-top: 5px; padding-bottom: 5px;width: auto;     min-width: 140px; background-size: 100% auto;}
nav.top_menu > ul > li.vertical-menu > ul > li > .sub-menu li.menu-item-has-children > a:before{display: none;}
nav.top_menu > ul > li.vertical-menu > ul > li > .sub-menu li.menu-item-has-children > a{font-weight: bold; margin-bottom: 0px;}
nav.top_menu > ul > li.vertical-menu > ul > li > ul > li{display: block; width:auto; z-index: 1; min-width:100%}
```

Comment: It would be good to add some html code also

Comment: Your question is mostly code, kindly add more description.